# Open API allowing to query the StackExchange user statistics

Tags: discussion

Is there any way to query the StackExchange's databases ?

I would for example like to know :

- how many users have subscribed to the Photography site
- what is the average number of SE websites users from a given region of the world have subscribed to
- the distribution of "reputation" for all SE users

Answer (score 1):

See https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks but here is what I see at the aforementioned address : "Stack Exchange is currently offline, we'll be back shortly!"

Comment: @SkippyFastol: Try now. You were unlucky.

Comment: @Matt: I was. Thank you.

Comment: I had initially linked to the https:// URL, then corrected it quickly. You were indeed unlucky.